# Finite index in $F_m$ implies non-trivial intersection

Tags: gr.group-theory

I was looking at a [paper](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/arjantse/Abs/revst-int.psBlockquote), and I saw this claim,

> It is obvious that if $H$ has finite index in $F_m$ then $H$ has non-trivial intersection with each of the non-trivial subgroups of $F_m$.

Why is this immediate?

Comment: Because $H$ intersects each subgroup in a finite index subgroup (bounded above by the index of $H$ in $F_m$) and because $F_m$ has no finite subgroups.

Comment: This is true, and easy to prove, for any torsion-free group.